# I want a compiler warning or error when I use a wrapped string in formatting

Tags: swift, cocoa

An error in my code that I frequently encounter is using a wrapped string while formatting. Especially around rules changing in Swift between versions it causes subtle bugs that aren't obvious by reading the code alone until I really look into the resulting string. It looks something like:

```
let myPostURL = "some/url/\(anObject.anID)"
```

Which then leads to:

```
"some/url/Optional(123)"
```

It's completely undesirable to see this, only a crash would be worse. Is there a way to let the compiler throw a warning or error every time this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest versions of Swift, there is a warning for this:

[image: screenshot]

This was implemented in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5110 and https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5195.

Comment: Nice find! I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't find that request! Whats the ETA in Xcode?

Comment: My screenshot is from the latest Xcode beta. So I would say the next stable version can be expected to have this too.  https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-1-release-process/